# C# add Image to cell dynamicly

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

Been playing with the UI of my program and have a little function that compares to cells on the same row and assigns a colour to that cell.
What I actually want now is to simply add an image UP or DOWN arrow to that cell. Unfortunately there seems to be no one liner which I find hard to believe.

Here's my current code:

```
DataGridViewImageCell p1 = new DataGridViewImageCell();

ParetoGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn() { CellTemplate = p1, FillWeight = 1, HeaderText = "p1", Name = "p1", Width = 30});




private void ShowArrow()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow paretoRow in ParetoGrid.Rows)
        {
            if ((paretoRow.Cells["Pareto6"].Value != null) &&   (Convert.ToInt32(paretoRow.Cells["CurrentPareto"].Value) < (Convert.ToInt32(paretoRow.Cells["NewPareto"].Value))))
            {
                paretoRow.Cells["p1"].Value = //image?;
            }
            else if ((paretoRow.Cells["Pareto6"].Value != null) && (Convert.ToInt32(paretoRow.Cells["CurrentPareto"].Value) > (Convert.ToInt32(paretoRow.Cells["NewPareto"].Value))))
            {
                ParetoGrid.Rows[paretoRow.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            }


        }
    }
```

Im hoping someone knows that there is a one liner. Oh and the column I want to add an image too is a DataGridViewImageCell.

Many thanks!

so far I simply create a new Image and then

```
paretoRow.Cells["p1"].Value = theImage;
```

Problem I get is  ERROR:formated cell has wrong type!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use DataGridTemplateColumn contains image control. General column dosen't support to show image.

Comment: could you shed a little light into what you mean? are you talking about on assigning the Image or are you talking about before?

Comment: or do you mean replace the DataGridViewImageCell with that?

Comment: I forgot that the column also needs to be of image type, that issue is resolved